# unresolved external symbol _____________ referenced in function _main (OPENGL C++)

Tags: c++, git

So I'm following this tutorial on OpenGL for C++ and followed everything the guy did. I am getting these errors and I don't know how to fix them.

```cpp
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _glfwWindowShouldClose referenced in function _main  GameEngine  C:\Users\Layne\source\repos\GameEngine\GameEngine\main.obj  1   
Error   LNK1120 9 unresolved externals  GameEngine  C:\Users\Layne\source\repos\GameEngine\Debug\GameEngine.exe 1   
Warning LNK4272 library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86' GameEngine  C:\Users\Layne\source\repos\GameEngine\Game Engine\GLFW\lib\glfw3.lib   1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _glfwCreateWindow referenced in function _main   GameEngine  C:\Users\Layne\source\repos\GameEngine\GameEngine\main.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _glfwInit referenced in function _main   GameEngine  C:\Users\Layne\source\repos\GameEngine\GameEngine\main.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _glfwMakeContextCurrent referenced in function _main GameEngine  C:\Users\Layne\source\repos\GameEngine\GameEngine\main.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _glfwPollEvents referenced in function _main GameEngine  C:\Users\Layne\source\repos\GameEngine\GameEngine\main.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback referenced in function _main GameEngine  C:\Users\Layne\source\repos\GameEngine\GameEngine\main.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _glfwSwapBuffers referenced in function _main    GameEngine  C:\Users\Layne\source\repos\GameEngine\GameEngine\main.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _glfwTerminate referenced in function _main  GameEngine  C:\Users\Layne\source\repos\GameEngine\GameEngine\main.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _glfwWindowHint referenced in function _main GameEngine  C:\Users\Layne\source\repos\GameEngine\GameEngine\main.obj  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warning LNK4272 library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86' GameEngine

Sounds like your library was built in 64-bit but you're building in 32-bit? If you're using Visual Studio you can change this at the top. Otherwise, let us know what platform and IDE you're developing on and please provide a link to the tutorial you're following.

Comment: ill try that. heres a link to the series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYZA1k8IKgM&list=PL6xSOsbVA1eYSZTKBxnoXYboy7wc4yg-Z&index=3

it may be one of the libraries that is x64. the rest is x86. ill find out what it is